# Why kernel lock validator called "lockdep"

Tags: linux, kernel, locking

I have been reading things like this:

> The first definition you refer to is part of the kernel lock validator, aka "lockdep".

I'm a kernel newbie and what bothers me is why the kernel lock validator called "lockdep"?

Does the "dep" stand for dependency? Please correct me if I'm wrong, thanks!

Comment: Yes. You can read about dependancy rules here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/locking/lockdep-design.rst

Comment: ok, thank you. I think this article explained why.

Comment: Please close the question if you already have a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the kernel lock validator checks a lot of lock depedancy inside the kernel so it is also called 'lockdep'.